# kendo grid number column formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, number-formatting

How can i use the jquery masking plugin with Kendo MVC Grid ?

I want to mask kendo grid column bound "phone number" column.

I am working on ASP.NET MVC4 application.

> > Or is there any other way to mask kendo mvc grid phone number column?

Comment: Mask it how? display or input for inline/popup edits/creates?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by masking? like hidding the column ?? 
if this is what you are looking for, you can set the hidden attribute of the column to true, it will hide the column. 
If you have the column menu available and do not want to see the column in that menu, set the menu attribute of the column to false.